# hortonworks Ambari + nifi selectHiveQL

Tags: apache-nifi, ambari

we use hortonworks' ambari packone and nifi, then we encountered a problem like this:

[image: nifi_selectHiveQL_bug_picture]

when the log shows that

> 2017-10-26 13:06:14,031 WARN [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.ExtensionManager Controller Service org.apache.nifi.dbcp.hive.HiveConnectionPool is bundled with its supporting APIs org.apache.nifi.dbcp.hive.HiveDBCPService. The service APIs should not be bundled with the implementations.
>
> 2017-10-26 13:06:14,031 ERROR [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.ExtensionManager Skipping Controller Service org.apache.nifi.dbcp.hive.HiveConnectionPool because it is bundled with its supporting APIs and requires instance class loading.
>
> 2017-10-26 13:06:14,050 WARN [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.ExtensionManager Component org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.SelectHiveQL is bundled with its referenced Controller Service APIs org.apache.nifi.dbcp.hive.HiveDBCPService. The service APIs should not be bundled with component implementations that reference it.

I searched source code and found in line 167 of [sourceCodeUrl](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-framework-bundle/nifi-framework/nifi-framework-nar-utils/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/nar/ExtensionManager.java) like this:

> "Skipping component %s because it is bundled with its referenced Controller Service APIs and requires instance class loading.", extensionType.getName()));

Thank the first one who answered me, i think you are right, and i post pictures below of all files in the lib, in which some nar files are developed by our own. thank you very much.

[allFilesInLib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awYBa.png)

[allFilesInBootStrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWgLY.png)

could anyone help me?

thank you very much

one of my workmates searched a webpage :
[brokenPipesURL](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/78305/broken-pipes-in-nifi.html)

i have tried it. May it can be useful for my first error.

Answer (score 0):

The error in the UI is unrelated to the error you showed from the logs.

The error in the UI is showing a socket exception which likely means there is some network connectivity issue between NiFi and the hosts where Hive processes are running.

The error in the log is an error that should have been fixed in the HDF 3.x release line. It would be helpful if you could show a listing of everything in /usr/hdf/current/nifi/lib

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but i can't post picture here, so i reedit the question above. thank you